# Is there an ISO 8601 format for representing week day and time?

Tags: iso8601

I'm trying to specify a format for week day and time combination. Since I've been using ISO 8601 for date time representation, I'm trying to fit weekday/time format as per 8601. It can be easily represented as

```
1T10:45
```

where 1 is the week day number (Monday as per 8601). But I'm not sure if this is a valid ISO 8601 representation. Any advice would be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ISO 8601 defines values for the days of the week but not a format representing only the day of the week (e.g. for unbounded recurring times). You should feel free to adopt the ISO 8601 notation for the day of the week but accept that whatever format you choose will not comply with ISO 8601 unless it specifies the year, the week number, and the day of the week within that week (as in the example `1985-W15-5` from ISO 8601).

Comment: Thanks Owen for the response. Actually, my use case is unbounded recurring time event. Do you have any suggestion on format for that? It feels date is must for valid ISO 8601 while time could be optional.

Comment: You can choose whatever format is most appropriate for your implementation. You might prefer to choose an existing standard such as [iCal](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.3.10) but it's not necessary. Also consider looking for libraries that do this for you, as recurrence is not a simple problem to solve.

Comment: I think I'm going to go ahead and use the ISO 8601 format YYYY-Www-D and fill out the year and week number with zeros. Monday becomes 0000-W00-1 and Sunday 8PM becomes 0000-W00-6T20.